# Python pause thread execution

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Is there a way to "pause" the main python thread of an application perminantly?

I have some code that fires off two threads

```
class start():
    def __init__(self):
        Thread1= functions.threads.Thread1()
        Thread1.setDaemon(True)
        Thread1.start()
        Thread2= functions.threads.Thread2()
        Thread2.setDaemon(True)
        Thread2.start()

        #Stop thread here
```

At the moment, when the program gets to the end of that function it exits (There is nothing else for the main thread to do after that), killing the threads which run infinately (Looping). How do I stop the main process from exiting? I can do it with a `while True: None` loop but that uses a lot of CPU and there's probably a better way.

Comment: Why are you starting another thread if you could execute the workload of one of your extra threads on the main thread instead? In other words, why are you creating two threads and want to make the main thread wait, instead of just spawning one thread and running the workload of Thread2 on the main thread?

Comment: `pass` would make more sense than `None` for an empty loop body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't do `setDaemon(True)` on the threads, the process will keep running as long as the threads run for.

The daemon flag indicates that the interpreter needn't wait for a thread. It will exit when only daemon threads are left.

Answer (score 4):

Use [join](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join):

```
Thread1.join()
Thread2.join()
```

---

Also note that `setDaemon` is the old API.

```
Thread1.daemon = True
```

is the preferred way now.

Comment: It does ignore Ctrl-c, but Ctrl-\ (SIGQUIT) can still be used to terminate the program.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of daemon threads is to *not* prevent the application from being terminated if any of them is still running. You obviously want your threads to keep the application process alive, so don't make them daemons.